# Gateway MX6450 specifications

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory

Can anyone tell me what the maximum capacity of RAM and hard drive this laptop can handle? Also would it support Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specs for [Gateway Mx6450](http://support.gateway.com/s/Mobile/Q106/Blade/5959sp2.shtml)

- [RAM Specs](http://www.crucial.eu/upgrade/compatible-memory-for/Gateway/MX6450/list.html) (2 x 1GB sockets)
- Hard drive: a few upgrade sites say up to 320GB, but since the original is a 100GB/4200rpm I don't know if the sys board will support a 5400rpm, probably best to call Gateway support and ask to be on the safe side.

Should support Windows 7 32 and 64 bit (AMD Turion64) definitely get the RAM upgrade if you do install 7.